Overload resolution through return type?
Function overload resolution doesn't take return type into account, however I came across a piece of code on cppreference
SFINAE aside, how is overload resolution happening here:
#include <iostream>
 
// This overload is added to the set of overloads if C is
// a class or reference-to-class type and F is a pointer to member function of C
template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((void)(c.*f)(), void())
{
    std::cout << "(1) Class/class reference overload called\n";
}
 
// This overload is added to the set of overloads if C is a
// pointer-to-class type and F is a pointer to member function of C
template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((void)((c->*f)()), void())
{
    std::cout << "(2) Pointer overload called\n";
}
 
// This overload is always in the set of overloads: ellipsis
// parameter has the lowest ranking for overload resolution
void test(...)
{
    std::cout << "(3) Catch-all overload called\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    struct X { void f() {} };
    X x;
    X& rx = x;
    test(x, &X::f);  // (1)
    test(rx, &X::f); // (1), creates a copy of x
    test(&x, &X::f); // (2)
    test(42, 1337);  // (3)
}

I have checked. This code works. So, is trailing return type being used for overload resolution here?

There's no overload resolution happening, it's all SFINAE. When you pass &x the first variant won't work because it would lead to an error, but the second can be used.

@Someprogrammerdude So essentially everything gets settled even before compiler reaches the overload resolution stage. Compiler first looks for the right template to instantiate. It has to figure out the return type as part of that, that's where it has to choose between (c.*f) or (c->*f) and SFINAE kicks in. Eventually, there's only one candidate in the overload set for each call to test(). Is this understanding correct?

SFINAE happens during overload resolution.

Look it like this depending on the template argument types a totally new function with a new function signature is generated (with a unqiue set of arguments types). So still no specialization happens on return type, it just happen to be that the new function can have a unique return type.

@Someprogrammerdude "There's no overload resolution happening, it's all SFINAE." and "SFINAE happens during overload resolution." — These your two sentences seem to contradict each other. At least, it's confusing.

@Someprogrammerdude I went through Cppreference link. The two paragraphs from Cppreference make it clear:
1) "Template argument deduction takes place after the function template name lookup (which may involve argument-dependent lookup) and before template argument substitution (which may involve SFINAE) and overload resolution."
2) "Substitution failure (that is, failure to replace template parameters with the deduced or provided template arguments) of a function template removes the function template from the overload set."

@Someprogrammerdude So you are correct in that there's no overload resolution happening here because SFINAE kicks in during template argument substitution. This results in only one viable candidate for the calls and there's nothing to 'resolve'


overload resolution doesn't take return type into account

They mean that given several viable overloads, they are not disambiguated based on the return type (on whether it matches how the return value is used, and so on).
On the other hand, when an overload is rejected due to a SFINAE-caught error, it doesn't matter if the error is in the return type or elsewhere.

"a SFINAE error" sounds wrong, "a substitution failure"?

@Caleth "SFINAE-caught error" perhaps.
